# How can I use unicode \u003c in C++?

Tags: c++, unicode

I want to use unicode \u003c in C++ like this.

```
const static string strUnicode = "\u003c";
```

But I got an error when compiling.

```
error: \u003c is not a valid universal character
```

I found that unicode character between \u0001 and \u009f will lead to the same compiled error. Is it a bug? How can I use these unicode character in C++ correctly？

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't that just ```"<"```?

Comment: to me it does compile correctly for me. I used gcc compiler. What about you?

Comment: But it does fail on: https://ideone.com/L2wkMh

Comment: Yes. It is "<". @TomCarpenter

Comment: I use gcc  4.1.2 to compile.@Arashium

Comment: Perhaps trying putting it in single quotes '\u003c' since it's a character and not a string

Comment: @P.Hinker how many bytes is each unicode character?

Comment: @Arashium it's a wide character so it's multi-byte.  That doesn't change the fact that it's a character.

Comment: Try it in a newer compiler, this works: http://ideone.com/zcCuFU

Comment: GCC 4.1.2 was released in February 2007, GCC 4.1.0 in February 2006. This is almost certainly fixed in a newer version.

Comment: @TomCarpenter  `"\u003c"` same as `"<"` when the source encoding is ASCII. (True _almost_ all the time.)

Answer (score 4):

Before C++11, C++ didn't allow Unicode escapes with a code point under 0xA0, except for 0x24 ($), 0x40 (@), and 0x60 (`).

In C++11 this restriction was lifted, and it allows the entire UCS range (0x0-0x10FFFF) except for surrogate code points (0xD800-0xDFFF).

C still has the same restrictions as C++98.

Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape (See the "Range of universal character names" section).

Answer (score 0):

(Edited according interjay's comment):

With C++, it should work, provided the used compiler and the used standard (e.g. `-std=c++11` for `g++`) is new enough.

With C, there is no solution, it is doomed;)

For example, if I wish to insert some Russian text into the code in UTF16 (which will be UTF-16LE or UTF-16BE depending on the platform), I cannot write this:

```
uint16_t ustr[]= u"\u043f\u0435\u0434\u0438\u0438\u0020\u2014\u0020";
```

Instead:

```
uint16_t ustr[]= {0x043f,0x0435,0x0434,0x0438,0x0438,0x0020,0x2014,0x0020,0};
```

Surrogate pairs don't work either:

```
uint16_t usp[] = u"\ud83c\udf54"; /* surrogate pair */
```

Edit: It might be hard to believe, but gcc-5.4 gave error on this code-snippet (yes, it must have happened during the pre-processing, and yes, it is between `#if 0` and `#endif`):

```
#if 0
Some \u sequences give errors like these:
error: \u0020 is not a valid universal character
error: \ud83c is not a valid universal character
error: \udf54 is not a valid universal character
#endif
```

Edit: the simplest program to reproduce the problem:

```
int main (void) { u"\u0020"; return 0; }
```

Results:

```
gcc (ver-5.4, -std=c11):     error: \u0020 is not a valid universal character
gcc (ver-10.2, -std=c11):    error: \u0020 is not a valid universal character
clang (ver-3.4.2, -std=c11): error: character ' ' cannot be specified by a universal character name
```

Comment: You're using the wrong types. A `u"..."` literal give a `char16_t` array, not `int16_t`. Once I fix that it compiles fine for me, on both old and new versions of GCC and clang. The surrogate code points aren't allowed, probably because they don't represent a character by themselves.

Comment: @interjay Sadly, that changed nothing in my case; I've added a minimal example and added some concrete results.

Comment: You're compiling as C. The question is about C++.

Comment: @interjay That's right, it depends on the language. I'll edit the answer accordingly.